# Can you provide guidance on Facebook graph API extended token permissions while in development mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app that is in development mode.  My personal Facebook account is the Admin for the app.  My understanding is that if that account authorizes the app via OAuth that it should have all permissions.  However, when I retrieve a token using that account it only has the public profile permission.  I also noticed that after retrieving the token, converting it to a long-term token, and then adding additional permissions via the API explorer that the new permissions are applied to the long term token (even though a new token is loaded into the API explorer console).

Am I wrong in my understanding that the admin, developer, and tester roles should have all permissions? Is there something else I should be doing to ensure that the token has all permissions?  Is adding permissions via the API explorer the only way to do it?

Here are the steps that I follow and what is experienced at each step:

1) I use Facebook Login via the Javascript SDK (with the ngx-facebook wrapper) initialized with the app ID of the my app that is in development mode.
2) I login with the Facebook account that is the admin for the app.
3) A short-term token is generated, which I convert to a long-term token using the /oauth/access_token endpoint.
4) I store the long-term token for future use.
5) I try to use the long-term token to retrieve the posts for a page that the admin account owns and get the following response:

```
"error":{"error":{"message":"(#10) To use \'Page Public Content Access\', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this \'Page Public Content Access\' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."
```

6) I check the permissions for the user using the long-term token and user ID and get the following response.  This explains the response above but I thought admin, developer, and tester roles were supposed to have access to all permissions.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

7)  I go to the API explorer console logged in as the admin of the developer account that contains my app, choose the manage_pages permission, and click "Get Access Token".  I get a new token back.
8)  I ignore that token and use the original token.  It can now successfully retrieve the posts for the page.
9)  I check the original token's permissions and learn the the process in the API explorer added the permissions to the original long-term token:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "permission": "manage_pages",
            "status": "granted"
        },
        {
            "permission": "pages_show_list",
            "status": "granted"
        },
        {
            "permission": "public_profile",
            "status": "granted"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and found the answer.  I'll answer it here in case others are struggling with this.

While it is true that all admin, developer, and tester users for an app in development have access to most of the available permissions you still have to pass the list of permissions that you want request in your facebook login call.

For example, using the Facebook Login Javscript SDK you would send the list in the 'scope' property of the options parameter.  This is what it looks like:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'manage_pages,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_insights,read_insights'});
```

And this is what it would look like if you are using the ngx-facebook wrapper for Angular:

```
this.facebook.login({scope: 'manage_pages,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_insights,read_insights' }).then
```

The fundamental thing that I missed is that Facebook Login requires the scope option.  Otherwise it defaults to only requesting the 'public_profile' option.